# how to read path which is original windows path form from a file in python?

Tags: python

I have a text file contains some path, for example, it contains:
c:\text\text1
c:\text\text2
.......
how can I read these file directory as correct path? I know that I can put 'r' before path to make it work, such as

```
path=r'c:\text\text1'
```

but this time I need to read these to a variable first, then I don't know which way or function works the same as you put a r before it? for example I have tried:

```
path='c:\text\text1'
path1=r'%s'%path
print os.listdir(path1)
```

It doesn't work.How should I do ?
thanks.

update in 06/28/2016
It seems that I made a stupid question, it is actually works using following code:

```
import os

f=open('path.txt','r')
lines=f.readlines()
path=lines[0]

print os.listdir(path)
```

I guess that if you read something from a text, it is raw and just like you put a r before it. In above example, the path.txt first line is 
c:\test\test1
and I chekced

```
path1=r'c:\test\test1'
path2='c:\test\test1'
path==path1
```

result is True

```
path=path2
```

result is False
So waht I worried is not exist! I really should have tried before I ask. thanks agian

Comment: so you are reading the paths from a file. right? and you want to store the paths in variables. and the problem is what? Do you get an error back saying that the files do not exist?

Comment: what do  you mean it doesn't work.  Can you post what your result is or what traceback you get?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you stored the path you read to variable path, just do this:

```
path = r'C:\Users\ShengFeng\Documents\April.txt'
path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\")
print(path) #prints: 'C:\\Users\\ShengFeng\\Documents\\April.txt'
```